# MYSQL Search table joined by two-way pivot table

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a database of exhibitions and artists. Each exhibition is associated with any number of artists, and joined by a pivot table, like so:

```
'exhibitions'
+-----+--------------------------+
| id  | title                    |
+-----+--------------------------+
| 358 | A Closed Circuit         |
| 360 | Do You Love Me?          |
| 361 | Romans                   |
| 364 | Men in Love              |
| 367 | Bien Hoa                 |
| 369 | Jokes                    |
| 370 | Speech                   |
| 373 | Shimabuku's Fish & Chips |
+-----+--------------------------+

'artists'
+-----+-----------------+----------------------+
| id  | first_name      | last_name            |
+-----+-----------------+----------------------+
| 301 | Roman           | Schramm              |
| 302 | Ben             | Schumacher           |
| 303 | Hugh            | Scott-Douglas        |
| 304 | Nina            | Beier and Marie Lund |
| 305 | Constant        | Dullaart             |
| 306 | Brenna          | Murphy               |
| 307 | Jaako           | Pallasvuo            |
| 308 | Nicolas         | Pelzer               |
| 309 | Jon             | Rafman               |
+-----+-----------------+----------------------+

'associations'
+-------+-------------+------+-------------+------+
| id    | a_t         | a_id | b_t         | b_id |
+-------+-------------+------+-------------+------+
| 21371 | exhibitions |  369 | artists     |  301 |
| 21373 | exhibitions | 1842 | artists     | 2644 |
| 21379 | exhibitions |  315 | artists     | 2644 |
| 27752 | exhibitions | 4015 | artists     | 2644 |
| 21848 | exhibitions |   71 | artists     | 2650 |
|    34 | artists     |    1 | exhibitions |    1 |
|    85 | artists     |    5 | exhibitions |   36 |
|    90 | artists     |    8 | exhibitions |   38 |
|    97 | artists     |   10 | exhibitions |   39 |
|    98 | artists     |   54 | exhibitions |   40 |
|   100 | artists     |   55 | exhibitions |   42 |
|   102 | artists     |   55 | exhibitions |   43 |
|   103 | artists     |  301 | exhibitions |  370 |
|   584 | exhibitions |  998 | venues      |   22 |
|  1234 | venues      |   15 | exhibitions |  370 |
+-------+-------------+------+-------------+------+

'venues'
+------+--------------------+
| id   | name               |
+------+--------------------+
|   22 | ACME               |
| 1116 | Adams and Ollman   |
|  510 | Adamski            |
| 1077 | Agustina Ferreyra  |
|   15 | Air de Paris       |
+------+--------------------+
```

I need to create a search that matches terms against:

- Exhibition titles
- Artists associated with the exhibition
- The venues associated with the exhibition

But, as you can see, the `associations` table has some entries that are swapped. Sometimes the exhibition is the "A" table, sometimes it's "B". Also, it's also not a simple pivot table - as you can see, it's making associations for all tables. It's what I have to work with, and breaking this into more succinct pivot tables (table A to B, instead of the current table A/B/C/D/E to A/B/C/D/E) would require a lot of refactoring elsewhere and is out of the question.

As an example: the artist David Leiske has the ID of `128`, and associations that go both ways:

```
mysql> select * from associations where (a_t = 'artists' AND a_id = 126 AND b_t = 'exhibitions') OR (a_t = 'exhibitions' AND b_id = 126 AND b_t = 'artists');

+-------+-------------+------+-------------+------+
| id    | a_t         | a_id | b_t         | b_id |
+-------+-------------+------+-------------+------+
| 10438 | artists     |  126 | exhibitions |  458 |
| 10772 | exhibitions |   55 | artists     |  126 |
| 27490 | artists     |  126 | exhibitions | 3877 |
| 27500 | artists     |  126 | exhibitions | 3878 |
| 28435 | artists     |  126 | exhibitions | 4378 |
| 28474 | artists     |  126 | exhibitions | 4379 |
| 28475 | artists     |  126 | exhibitions | 4380 |
+-------+-------------+------+-------------+------+
```

These two queries are giving me what I need, separately:

```
SELECT exhibitions.id as result_id, 'exhibitions' as result_type, exhibitions.title AS result_title, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', artists.first_name, artists.last_name)) AS col_3
FROM exhibitions
LEFT JOIN associations AS associations ON (associations.b_id = exhibitions.id AND b_t = 'exhibitions' AND a_t = 'artists')
LEFT JOIN artists ON (associations.a_id = artists.id AND a_t = 'artists')
WHERE
  (artists.id IS NOT NULL)
  AND ((CONCAT_WS(' ', artists.first_name, artists.last_name)) RLIKE 'Lieske')
  OR (exhibitions.title RLIKE 'Lieske')
GROUP BY exhibitions.id

+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| result_id | result_type | result_title                                | col_3        |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|       458 | exhibitions | Deformation Professionelle                  | David Lieske |
|      3877 | exhibitions | Der africanishe Stuhl von marcel Breuer     | David Lieske |
|      3878 | exhibitions | Imerium in Imperio                          | David Lieske |
|      4378 | exhibitions | A Greater Administration of Lower Interests | David Lieske |
|      4379 | exhibitions | Platitude Normale                           | David Lieske |
|      4380 | exhibitions | Fantôme Mains Sur                           | David Lieske |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And:

```
SELECT exhibitions.id as result_id, 'exhibitions' as result_type, exhibitions.title AS result_title, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', artists.first_name, artists.last_name)) AS col_3
FROM exhibitions
LEFT JOIN associations AS associations ON (associations.a_id = exhibitions.id AND a_t = 'exhibitions' AND b_t = 'artists')
LEFT JOIN artists ON (associations.b_id = artists.id AND b_t = 'artists')
WHERE
  (artists.id IS NOT NULL)
  AND ((CONCAT_WS(' ', artists.first_name, artists.last_name)) RLIKE 'Lieske')
  OR (exhibitions.title RLIKE 'Lieske')
GROUP BY exhibitions.id

+-----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| result_id | result_type | result_title | col_3        |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
|        55 | exhibitions | Adequate     | David Lieske |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I could UNION the two queries into one - this gives me the final result that I'm going for. But, I'll be building this query dynamically - this is just one (troublesome) portion of a more comprehensive search, and it would be much easier if I could handle this A:B / B:A relationship in a more dynamic way.

I've tried adding an OR to the join:

```
SELECT exhibitions.id as result_id, 'exhibitions' as result_type, exhibitions.title AS result_title, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', artists.first_name, artists.last_name)) AS col_3
FROM exhibitions
LEFT JOIN associations AS associations ON (associations.b_id = exhibitions.id AND b_t = 'exhibitions' AND a_t = 'artists')
  OR (associations.a_id = exhibitions.id AND a_t='exhibitions' AND b_t='artists')
LEFT JOIN artists ON (associations.a_id = artists.id AND a_t = 'artists')
  OR (associations.b_id = artists.id AND b_t = 'artists')
WHERE
  (artists.id IS NOT NULL)
  AND ((CONCAT_WS(' ', artists.first_name, artists.last_name)) RLIKE 'Lieske')
  OR (exhibitions.title RLIKE 'Lieske')
GROUP BY exhibitions.id
```

but, I know I'm doing something wrong, because the query takes over 30 seconds, whereas the UNION'd query took 0.07.

What am I doing wrong here?

Lastly: how do I also JOIN `venues.name` to the table and add that to the query?

Sample searches:

- `RLIKE 'art|acme'`, an expected result: The exhibition(s) that had `art` in the title, and was at the venue `ACME`
- `RLIKE 'davis|paris'`, an expected result: The exhibition(s) including an artist with a first or last name of `davis`, which took place at `Air de Paris`

(I realize these are going to bring up all of the OR matches - but, this post is getting long enough, so I can make another one about ranking the results..)

Comment: First fix the associations table. Surely it needs nothing more than two columns - artist_id and exhibition_id

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @Strawberry. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with this more complicated associations table. I've updated the post to explain it a little better.

Comment: So it's out of the question. Well, so am I. Have fun. ;-)